# Non business logic database access in DDD

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, domain-driven-design

just starting with DDD. I understand that all the domain entities and their logic should be kept in Domain layer along with repository interfaces. In my application I store some data in the database that is used to construct parts of the user interface (presentation layer) at run time. Where should I keep the poco classes and repository interfaces for such types, in Application layer or Domain layer. I can not make out because these objects will not have  any domain related business logic but they need to be hydrated from the database and I am using EF so for data access I will need entities and repositories so to me obvious choice is to keep them with all other entities and repository interfaces in domain layer but that breaks DDD rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to think of it is this - if you had to replace EF with stored procedures for performance reasons, you should not have to modify your domain code.  So anything that blocks that needs to be hidden behind an interface and made replaceable.

Repositories CAN be a part of domain logic.  However what should not be is the mechanism for persistence.  This can easily be encapsulated into a DAL service or other object, which of course is programmed to an IDALService interface.  So when you need to switch persistance (for example, moving from EF to a NoSQL solution) you simply write an alternative version that implements the IDALService interface, and you're good to go.  The repositories can still do the logic within them, but are now using a new way to store them (this is an Inversion of Control idea).

As for the POCO objects, in DDD the real question is what do they represent?  Are they entities, that need to be persisted?  Are they value objects?  Don't let the technology (EF) determine what the structure of your object model is, instead provide means to translate to an application scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've answered your own question:

> In my application I store some data in the database that is used to
>   construct parts of the user interface (**presentation layer**) at run
>   time.

Access to data that is used to serve the UI should be encapsulated in the presentation layer. This is different from the application layer in that a DDD application layer implements use cases by orchestrating repositories and delegating to appropriate entities, domain services - it forms an API around your domain layer. Different presentation implementations can use the same application service.

However, different presentation layer implementations may require different data. Therefore, place presentation data access directly in the presentation layer. This can be implemented with EF which is not exclusive for DDD scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In the Application layer. Keep the domain intact and isolated.